# Check which extended interface does json belong to

Tags: typescript

I have a parent interface which is extended by two other interfaces

```
interface ParentItem {
  foo: number;
}

interface ChildItemOne extends ParentItem {
  fooone: string;
}

interface ChildItemTwo extends ParentItem {
  footwo : string;
}
```

I have a function that accepts a ParentItem, how do I find out if it belongs to ChildItemOne or ChildItemTwo

`if(obj.footwo) or if(obj.fooone) // obj = ParentItem obj` leads to errors since footwo or fooone arent a part of ParentItem

Comment: Look for type guards in TypeScript's documentation.

Comment: yes that works but I was hoping for another way if at all there is

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I see so I create two objects obj1 as ChildItemOne  and obj2 as ChildItemTwo ?

Comment: You do both in two different IFs. The IF with your type guards will do the typing automatically.

Comment: oneobj = obj as ChildItemOne
twoobj = obj as ChildItemTwo
if(oneobj.fooone) { // something }
if(twoobj.footwo) { // something } ?
is this okay @GuillaumeF.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

[Test in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcBJSBbZAbwChlkYB7CgLmRAFc8AjaAbmIF9jjRJZEUAYQAWwADYATXBDwB5ECggAPSCAkBnNBixhpBEmUpUFtdWCigA5uy49w0eEmQjxU-ABUA7hWTLVGrUwcfCJSciowb2RTcysbbmIAekTkdXpLSwgzYAoQZABGYhh6EAQwHLy0jKzy3PzkAAomOAAvWhdJPXkUAB9nUU6PbwBKULIyYBgGgHIjXIhp5FBkZpbRg3HN1YA6OYV2Tc3kldalzQ63GW6wsg5fMXUUDcOTlt2I7wOX5GPVs-7XHovBQbsguLYkikqplsrlkAAmIolMoVVLpGG1EDwxqrWjoIK6fDrUGTBrAdRdBRNVrDYnfV7vYwQL63e6PJZTclA7zUtZ0747IyRCgssGcbjFUqYs6UlANChMABWeO0wRkw1oCsV-wusrG40wYHoUDysyo80Wyy18SRUtRXKGPnlSpVBL0GuQWp1A0ueGB%20rIhuNpqF3kteWtnCAA)

Either use the union type `ChildItemOne | ChildItemTwo` as parameter and check if one property is part of the object...

```js
function suggestion1 (baz: ChildItemOne | ChildItemTwo) {
    if('fooone' in baz) {
        baz.fooone;
        // baz is ChildItemOne
    } else {
        baz.footwo;
        // baz is ChildItemTwo
    }
}
```

... or use the generic type `ParentItem` as parameter and define type guard functions.

```js
function suggestion2 (baz: ParentItem) {
    if(isItemOne(baz)) {
        baz.fooone;
    } else if(isItemTwo(baz)) {
        baz.footwo;
    }
}

function isItemOne (obj: ParentItem): obj is ChildItemOne {
    return 'fooone' in obj;
}

function isItemTwo (obj: ParentItem): obj is ChildItemTwo {
    return 'footwo' in obj;
}
```